# Responsive CSS background image - how to make content follow

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have CSS background image in header div. Image responsiveness works fine but I cant get it work so that content under header image "follows" image when it resizes.

Problem is that when I give height value to header image div then div height is fixed. And when I do not give height image is not shown at all.

See working example [`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/0bjgfo16)

Any help how to fix?

Comment: Try using <img> tag inside header div instead of css background-image

Comment: Not clear what's meant when you say header image "follows" when image resizes.

Comment: It means that content under header image should be attached bottom of header image - not leaving space between header image and content.

Comment: Any solution to make this work without <img> tags?

Comment: This might be helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430206/how-can-i-scale-an-image-in-a-css-sprite

Comment: If you are only concerned about the space or getting a responsive layout where even after resize, header attaches itself to the content? If it's only about space, `p { margin: 0; }` should work. Browsers tend to attach their own CSS for certain elements like p which you manually need to override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your solution:

**Issue:-** Height value in percentage doesn't work, until unless it has been used in any position layer.

**Solution:-** Instead of height. Use "padding-bottom" OR "padding-top" value to make height responsive. Becasue percentage values work well with "padding".

The calculation is very simple to get the relevant responsive height value of any background image.

**For Example:-** If Background image dimensions are (1200 width) x (450 height) Pixels. Then image responsive "height" value would be: "37.5%"

**Formula:-** Y (×) 100 (÷) X. Which is (450×100÷1200) = 37.5%

**Solution URL:-** http://sandeepparashar.com/stackoverflow/responsive-css-background-image-height.html

**Code:-**

```
.custom-header-option {
    padding-bottom:37.5%; /* This will make height responsive */
    background-image: url('http://unplugged.ee/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/frank2.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
}
```

If need more help, most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is to remove the "white space" gap?

Try this code: http://jsfiddle.net/0bjgfo16/4/

**HTML**

```
    <img src="http://unplugged.ee/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/frank2.jpg" />

    <div class="content-wrap">
        <p>here is content</p>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    * { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
    img { max-width: 100%; float: left; }

    .content-wrap {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: grey;
        color: #fff;
        float: left;
    }
```